# Could not find property nor field

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have created private field and initializing it in constructor of class.

```
#region "Private Fields"

private readonly IList<Ethnicity> _ethnicities;
private readonly IList<Contact> _contacts;
private readonly IList<Address> _addresses;
private readonly IList<Dependent> _dependents;
private readonly IList<InsuredType> _insuredTypes;
private const string PrimaryEmailCode = "EML";
private const string SecondaryEmailCode = "EM2";
private const string HomePhoneCode = "HPH";
private const string CellPhoneCode = "CPH";
private const string PrimaryInsured = "PRIMARY";
private const string DependentInsured = "DEPENDENT";
private const string PermenantAddressCode = "PERM";
private const string MailingAddressCode = "MAIL";

#endregion

#region "Constructors"
public Insured()
{
    _ethnicities = new List<Ethnicity>();
    _contacts = new List<Contact>();
    _addresses = new List<Address>();
    _dependents = new List<Dependent>();
    _insuredTypes = new List<InsuredType>();
}

#endregion

#region "Public Properties"

public virtual IEnumerable<InsuredType> Insuredtypes
{
    get { return _insuredTypes; }
}

public virtual string InsuredType
{
    get
    {
        if (InsuredStatus == "ACTIVE")
        {

            var type = _insuredTypes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now);
            if (type != null)
            {
                var status = type.InsuredTypeDescription == "PRIM" ? PrimaryInsured : DependentInsured;
                return status;
            }
        }

        if (InsuredStatus == "EXPIRED" || InsuredStatus == "MERGED")
        {
            var type =
                _insuredTypes.Where(n => n.ExpiryDate < DateTime.Now)
                             .OrderByDescending(n => n.ExpiryDate)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
            if (type != null)
            {
                var status = type.InsuredTypeDescription == "PRIM" ? PrimaryInsured : DependentInsured;

                return status;
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get an exception that `_insuredTypes could not found in Insured class`.

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Here is the mapping of Insured Class

```
internal class InsuredMap : CacheableEntityClassMap<Entities.Insured>
{
    public InsuredMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();

        Table("Insured");
        Id(x => x.Id, "InsuredId");

        Map(x => x.Gender,Convert.ToString("SexCd")).CustomType<TrimmedStringUserType>();
        Map(x => x.GradDate,    Convert.ToString("GradMthYrNum")).CustomType<TrimmedStringUserType>();
        Map(x => x.SrId, Convert.ToString("SIDIdNum")).CustomType<TrimmedStringUserType>();
        Map(x => x.SchoolId, Convert.ToString("SchoolIdTxt")).CustomType<TrimmedStringUserType>();
        Map(x => x.Ssn, Convert.ToString("SocSecNumTxt")).CustomType<TrimmedStringUserType>();
        Map(x => x.DateOfBirth,    Convert.ToString("BirthDt")).CustomType<TrimmedStringUserType>();
        Map(x => x.ExpDt, ("ExpDt"));
```

And here is mapping of insured types

```
HasMany(x => x.Insuredtypes)
    .KeyColumn("InsuredId")
    .LazyLoad()
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.All();
```

Comment: Which line? Where do you get the error?

Comment: Is this a compile time error? If so, is all your code in the same class?  And where does the `Insured` class live?

Comment: The code i posted above is part of insured class

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the `_insuredTypes` property set to private, so NHibernate can't find this field to map against. If you want to map this and have it also be Read Only, you need to look at different mapping options than the default.

For extra help - you should post your mappings.